# How can I download a url that contains left and right quotes with Wget?

Tags: download

I'm trying to download a file from a url with Wget on Windows 7, which contains boath left and right quotes. It could look something like this:
[https://x.xx.com/xxx/92-prelude_op.28_to_15_“raindrop”_(f._chopin).mp3](https://x.xx.com/xxx/92-prelude_op.28_to_15_%E2%80%9Craindrop%E2%80%9D_(f._chopin).mp3)

I'm trying to download it with Wget to presserve the file's time stamp. However, when I try to download it, Wget first gives a 400 error, stating bad request, and then gives "Unable to establish SSL connection."
I've tried enclosing the url in normal quotes, i.e: "https://x.xx.com/xxx/92-prelude_op.28_to_15_“raindrop”_(f._chopin).mp3", but with no luck.
What can I do at this point?

Thank you.

Comment: Find out what the ascii value is and convert that to hexadecimal, then use %## instead of the character. Its the same you can use a space. A space is ascii 32, or hex 20. So `File%20Name` is the same thing as writing an url with `File Name`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I don't really know much about those languages. I tried converting those quotes to hexdecimal, which gave %201C and %201D, which then just gave a 404 error in Wget. Could you maybe give an example with these characters?

Comment: Try putting the URL in single quotes. This will keep the shell from interpreting the contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with single quotation marks. Something like:

```
wget 'https://x.xx.com/xxx/92-prelude_op.28_to_15_“raindrop”_(f._chopin).mp3'
```

This will make shell to ignore the "special" usage of some symbols.

This work fine in Linux. On Windows if you have installed Windows Subsystem for Linux you have already `bash` where such technique to escape special symbols will work.

Comment: I think you beat my comment by about 15 seconds...

Comment: Thank you, but that just made Wget give "Schem missing". I forgot to mention that I'm running this on Windows. I'll update the main question.

Comment: @akse0435, see my edited answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I know nothing about Linux. I'm just using wget.exe on Windows.

Comment: @akse0435, this is just a shell which can be used to escape odd characters. You do not need to install any Linux

Comment: I see. I'm running Windows 7 though, and it doesn't appear to be available for Windows 7.

Comment: @akse0435, in such case have you try to use browser to download this particular file? Also are you OK to use third party tool to do the task?

Comment: I'm trying to download it with Wget to preserve the time stamp. It downloads just fine with Chrome, but Chrome doesn't preserve the time stamp.